# Amplify Schema complains because argument type is not 'List<UserWallet>?'

Tags: swift, swiftui, aws-amplify

I'm trying to add new data locally using DataStore and this is the error I'm getting:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'User' to expected argument type 'List<UserWallet>?'
```

I have the following schema defined (a many-many between user and wallet):

```
type Wallet @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  address: String
  users: [UserWallet] @connection(keyName: "byWallet", fields: ["id"])
}

type User @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  UserWallets: [UserWallet] @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
}

type UserWallet @model(queries: null) @key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userID", "walletID"]) @key(name: "byWallet", fields: ["walletID", "userID"]) @auth(rules: [{allow: public}, {allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  userID: ID!
  walletID: ID!
  user: User! @connection(fields: ["userID"])
  wallet: Wallet! @connection(fields: ["walletID"])
}
```

I'm trying to add some data following the [official docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/relational/q/platform/ios#updated-schema), so I tried this:

```
let newUser = User(name: "Arturo")
let newWallet = Wallet(address: "0xewefwef32", users: newUser)


Amplify.DataStore.save(newUser) { userResult in
    switch userResult {
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error adding post - \(error.localizedDescription)")
    case .success:
        Amplify.DataStore.save(newWallet) { newWalletResult in
            switch newWalletResult {
            case .success:
                print("User saved!")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error adding newWallet - \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting the error above. What's failing that process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tons of hours I found the answer, it was looking for the schema relationship name, which in this case I had named wallet, oh boy... Any way, this is the solution in case someone comes across the same issue:

```
let newWallet = Wallet(address: "0xewefwef32", user: newUser.wallet)
```

notice the newUser.wallet at the end. That was the tricky part :)